# Django admin Editing a product with properties and property types

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin, django-filter

I have a 3 models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    properties = models.ManyToManyField(PropertyVar, blank=True)

class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, default='')

class PropertyVar(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, default='')
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

How to make it possible in the admin panel to add/edit for the product (Product) properties (PropertyVar) with a choice of property type (Property)?

Thanx!

filter_horizontal just displays all propertyVar in a row... It becomes unclear which property these propertyVar refer to...

Comment: your question is not clear. Do you want to create a PropertyVar in Product admin panel while add/edit?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.